# Why does Ginzburg's construction of irreps of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$/the partial Springer resolution have to go via the enveloping algebra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Chriss-Ginzburg's book goes through a Lagrangian construction of the enveloping algebra, with a certain map given from the enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ to a certain homology of a Steinberg-like variety. The construction involves considering $n$-step partial flags inside some ambient space $\mathbb{C}^d$, unlike the usual Springer resolution which looks at complete flags.

The construction simply defines what the Chevalley generators of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ are sent to, but nothing else is said. My question is more of morally why this should be the case:

> Why do we require the enveloping algebra at all, and where does the construction specifically involve $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{sl}_n)$?

I am vaguely aware that this construction is a specification of a more general construction of the quantum enveloping algebra, which is detailed in a paper of Beilinson-Lusztig-MacPherson (and how they are able to construct the entire algebra, and not only the positive part as in previous work by Ringel), however I am looking for a hopefully more simple and concise answer to my question above.

Comment: The construction does not need to explicitly go via the universal enveloping algebra, but stating the theorem as “there is a surjection of algebras from UEA to homology” makes things precise and clear. What really happens is that you have an algebra (homology) with some elements that look “like they are obeying the same relations as the Chevalley operators”. Making that last sentence more precise means showing that those elements obey the Serre relations (or the UEA equivalent of them), and by Serre’s theorem this is the same as saying the map from the UEA is a homomorphism.

Comment: That makes sense. There's no deeper reason for why though?

Comment: I don't think there is a deeper reason. Any map of Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g} \to A$, where $A$ is an associative algebra equipped with the Lie bracket, lifts to a map of algebras $U(\mathfrak{g}) \to A$ by the universal property of the UEA. The kernel of the second map is useful (it can tell you things about how close to $U(\mathfrak{g})$ the algebra $A$ is), while the kernel of the first map is not so useful.

Comment: @Joppy for what it's worth, since this discussion I have realised that it seems as though we do need to pass through the UEA in order to *prove* that we get irreps arising from the convolution algebra on the (top-dimensional Borel-Moore) homology of the Steinberg variety $Z$. In particular, in both the book and Ginzburg's original 1991 paper, this proof is left as a generalisation of some "main result" in Beilinson-Lusztig-MacPherson (who work with quantum $\mathcal{U}_q(\mathfrak{gl}_n$), although I haven't figured out how this is proven yet...

Comment: That being said, the results are also proven via sheaf-theoretic methods and semi-smallness of the Springer resolution in Chapter 8 of the same book, so it may be that we don't need the UEA after all (although I also don't understand mostly all of that (yet...))